# require_tree stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

I have a few javascript files in `assets/javascript` that I'd like to include in the views. My application.js hasn't changed since the default:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

At some point the scripts ran successfully in the view without me having to write anything in the view template. When I looked at the source code in the browser, I saw that their paths are controlled by turbolinks. But after doing some minor changes (I really can't put my finger on anything important I changed - nothing connected to turbolinks anyway), it suddenly stopped working, and now none of the javascript files is loaded.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I added `= javascript_include_tag 'application'` and it fixed the problem. I have no idea how it worked before that.